# Массив на языке bash - хранится ли локально на стеке?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Здравствуйте. Вопрос следующий. Допустим я в рекурсивной функции rec, пишу следующее определение массива:
local dep = ('cat $1') (backticks естественно)
таким образом все содержание файла переданным параметром я размешаю в массив.
Далее снова вызываю rec, восстановится ли после возвращения исходное значение массива, точно также как в Си и Си++, ведь отличия только в синтаксисе заполнения массива, в обоих случаях, с использованием local переменная или массив в данном случае сохраняются на стеке, верно ли данное предположение ?

Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: а самому проверить сложно?

Comment: на данный момент затрудняюсь по техническим причинам, думал кто-то подскажет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример с массивом из двух элементов

```
#!/bin/bash
f(){
local x
x=($x $1 $2)
echo ${x[*]}
[ $1 -lt 4 ] && f $(($1+1)) $2
echo ${x[*]}
}
f 1 2
```

Судя по выводу

```
1 2
2 2
3 2
4 2
4 2
3 2
2 2
1 2
```

массивы сохраняются в каждом вызове свои.

Если `local` убрать массив общий изменяется

```
1 2
1 2 2
1 3 2
1 4 2
1 4 2
1 4 2
1 4 2
1 4 2
```

Comment: Отлично, благодарю.